# Matching first substring within a variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, rhel

I have 2 variables `value` and `backup` with following values:

```
value = 'abc'

backup = urls://string1abc.com, urls://string1cde.com, urls://string1efg.com, urls://string1abc.com
```

I want to check the `first substring` before comma within the `backup` variable and then grep for for `$value` and if it matches then `$test=PASS`

In above example, `$backup` contains `abc` in the `first` and `last` substring. However, I only want to check the the `first substring` which is `urls://string1abc.com`

I have the following command but it checks for all substrings within `backup`

```
grep -qs $value $backup && test='PASS' || test='FAIL'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
if [[ ${backup%%,*} = *"$value"* ]]; then 
    test=pass
else
    test=fail
fi
```

Comment: It is returning `PASS` even when `$backup` is `null`  This is not correct.

Comment: @meallhour Very hard to believe. Can you post the actual input that this fails for?

Comment: I am just setting `backup` as `empty` and trying to run it

Comment: `value=abc; backup=""` works fine for me and outputs `fail`. Doesn't it for you? See: https://ideone.com/dZjdwq